# Can every bounded functional be written as a linear combination of two bounded hermitian functionals?

Tags: c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^{\ast}$-algebra. Let $\rho$ be a bounded linear functional on $A.$ Does there exist bounded hermitian functionals $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ on $A$ such that $\rho = \rho_1 + i \rho_2\ $?

Any suggestion in this regard would be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: $\rho_1=\frac {A+A^{*}} 2$, $\rho_2=\frac {A-A^{*}} {2i}$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy$:$ Do you mean $\rho_1 = \frac {\rho + \rho^{\ast}} {2}$ and $\rho_2 = \frac {\rho - \rho^{\ast}} {2i}$ where $\rho^{\ast} : a \mapsto \overline {\rho (a)}\ $?

Comment: Yes, sorry! I wrote $A$ for $\rho$.

Comment: $\rho^{*}$ is  the adjoint of $\rho$.

Comment: But we need also to check that whether $\rho_{i} (a^{\ast}) = \overline {\rho_{i} (a)}$ for $i = 1,2$ or not; although it is an easy verification. Here $\rho_1$ is purely real-valued with $\rho_1 (a^{\ast}) = \rho_1 (a)$ and hence $\rho_1$ is hermitian. But $\rho_2$ is purely imaginary-valued with $\rho_2 (a^{\ast}) = - \rho_2 (a)$ and hence $\rho_2$ is also hermitian. So we are done!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think you can turn this comment into an answer.

Comment: @QuantumSpace I am not doing that becasue this question **has been answered many times** on MSE and the poof is also available in many books. Frankly, I thinhk this question should be deleted.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy If that's the case, I completely agree with you.

Comment: @AntonioClaire: what you propose is not even linear. It should be $\rho^*(a)=\overline{\rho(a^*)}$.

Comment: @Martin Argerami$:$ Yes I had to recheck it again. Thanks for pointing that out.